# Bootstrap 4 navbar content vertical alignment ignored in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am placing my navbar over a background image (using class bg-light) with the navbar located at bottom of image. But in IE 11 the navbar appears at top of image.
I am aware IE 11 has issues with Bootstrap alignment and this is probably one of them, but wonder if there is any workaround to get navbar to stay at bottom of image in IE?
Here is the stripped down code:

```
<style>
.bg-light{
    background-image:url("https://www.restinbeing.com/images/header3.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 140px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
</style> 

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light d-flex align-items-end "> 
<div class="nav-content">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown menubar"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About </a> 
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 1</a>
                </div>
                </li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `min-height` with flex was the issue, replacing it with `height` did the trick. See: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-3 The suggested workaround also worked, and would be helpful where `min-height` was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [known issue](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-3) of IE. The `min-height` property will not work when used with Flexbox layout in IE. We can use css-tricks to fix it in IE. Give the parent a flex column container in Flexbox layout.

CSS of parent in Flexbox layout:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

In your code, you need to target IE 11 in CSS to make the style only work for IE. You can create a media query using `-ms-high-contrast`. Because `-ms-high-contrast` is Microsoft-specific (and only available in IE 10+), it will only be parsed in Internet Explorer 10 and greater.

So you just need to add the following code in your css style:

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) { 
      /* IE10+ CSS styles go here */          
     html, body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems to fix it. Most grateful.

Comment: I responded too soon. It was working fine till I added the navbar toggler button: 
`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light d-flex align-items-end "> <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button> `

Comment: Do you add the `<button>` [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vjJZ.png) in `<nav>`? Is there any style for `<button>`? I added the button, but it doesn't show in neither IE nor Chrome. The results are the same as when the button not being added.

Comment: That button only shows in responsive mode. Nevertheless its code was still messing with full-width pages. However, i've managed to solve it by adjusting my design and replacing `min-height` with `height`  Thanks again for your help.